# Trying to implement d3.js version 4 as a polymer component

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to implement the [Directed Graph Editor](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) under D3.js version 4 instead of version 3 and also implementing zoom and pan.  I am also trying to implement it as a Polymer component.

I have the start of this implemented in the following github repository https://github.com/powerxhub/emh-d3-force-directed-graph.git.

I have the zoom working, but the selection of the nodes and links are is not working. What am I missing?

The body of the component is the following:

```
<script>
var nodeEnter;
var nodeExit;
var linkEnter;
var g;
var color;

Polymer({

  is: 'emh-d3-force-directed-graph',

  properties: {
    graph: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true, 
      value:  { nodes: [
      {id: 0, reflexive: false, group: 0 },
      {id: 1, reflexive: true, group: 1  },
      {id: 2, reflexive: false, group: 0 }
      ], links: [{ source:0, target: 1 }, { source:1, target: 2 }, { source:2, target: 0 }] },
      observer: '_graphChanged'
    },
    selected_node: { type: Object, notify: true },
    mousedown_node: { type: Object },
    selected_link: { type: Object, notify: true },
    mousedown_link: { type: Object },
    mouseup_link: { type: Object }
    },

  created: function() {
    console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' was created');
  },

  ready: function() {
  console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' has local DOM initialized');

  },

  attached: function() {
    console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' was attached');
    var aa = this.$.polymerForce.getBoundingClientRect();
    var svg_height = aa.height;
    var svg_width = aa.width;

    g = d3.select(this.$.polymerForce)
    .append('g')
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .on("mousemove", this.mousemove)
    .on("mousedown", this.mousedown)
    .on("mouseup", this.mouseup)
    ;
    d3.select(this.$.polymerForce).append("rect")
    .attr("width", svg_width)
    .attr("height", svg_height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all")
    .call(d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoomed));

    function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

    this.force = d3.forceSimulation(this.graph.nodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(this.graph.links).id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(svg_width / 2, svg_height / 2));
    if (this.force) {
      this.redraw();
    }
  },

  detached: function() {
    console.log(this.localName + '#' + this.id + ' was detached');
  },


  _graphChanged: function() {
    console.log("foo");
    if (this.force) {
      redraw();
    }
  },
  mousedown: function() {
    if (!this.mousedown_node && !this.mousedown_link) {
      // allow panning if nothing is selected
      g.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom"), rescale);
      return;
    }
  },

  mousemove: function() {
    if (!this.mousedown_node) return;

    // update drag line
    this.drag_line
    .attr("x1", this.mousedown_node.x)
    .attr("y1", this.mousedown_node.y)
    .attr("x2", d3.svg.mouse(this)[0])
    .attr("y2", d3.svg.mouse(this)[1]);

  },

  mouseup: function() {
    if (this.mousedown_node) {
      // hide drag line
      this.drag_line
      .attr("class", "drag_line_hidden")

      if (!this.mouseup_node) {
        // add node
        var point = d3.mouse(this),
        nodeEnter = {x: point[0], y: point[1]},
        n = this.graph.nodes.push(nodeEnter);

        // select new node
        this.selected_node = nodeEnter;
        this.selected_link = null;

        // add link to mousedown node
        this.graph.links.push({source: mousedown_node, target: nodeEnter});
      }

      redraw();
    }
    // clear mouse event vars
    this.mousedown_node = null;
    this.mouseup_node = null;
    this.mousedown_link = null;
    //this.resetMouseVars();
  },

  resetMouseVars: function() {
    this.mousedown_node = null;
    this.mouseup_node = null;
    this.mousedown_link = null;
  },

  tick: function() {
    linkEnter.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodeEnter.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  },

  // rescale g
  rescale: function() {
    trans=d3.event.translate;
    scale=d3.event.scale;

    g.attr("transform",
    "translate(" + trans + ")"
    + " scale(" + scale + ")");
  },

  // redraw force layout
  redraw: function() {

    linkEnter = g.selectAll(".link")
      .data(this.graph.links).enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("stroke", "#666")
      .attr("stroke-width", "5")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .on("mousedown", 
            function(d) { 
              this.mousedown_link = d; 
              if (this.mousedown_link == this.selected_link) 
                this.selected_link = null;
              else 
                this.selected_link = this.mousedown_link; 
              this.selected_node = null; 
              this.redraw(); 
            }
      )
      ;

    linkEnter
      .classed("link_selected", function(d) { return d === this.selected_link; });

    linkExit = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(this.graph.links).exit().remove();

    nodeEnter = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(this.graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .on("mousedown", 
              function(d) { 
              // disable zoom
                //g.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom"), null);

                this.mousedown_node = d;
                if (this.mousedown_node == this.selected_node) 
                  this.selected_node = null;
                else 
                  this.selected_node = this.mousedown_node; 
                this.selected_link = null; 

                // reposition drag line
                this.drag_line
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("x1", mousedown_node.x)
                    .attr("y1", mousedown_node.y)
                    .attr("x2", mousedown_node.x)
                    .attr("y2", mousedown_node.y);

                redraw(); 
              }
      )
      .on("mousedrag",
              function(d) {
                // redraw();
              }
      )
      .on("mouseup", 
              function(d) { 
                if (this.mousedown_node) {
                  this.mouseup_node = d; 
                  if (this.mouseup_node == this.mousedown_node) { resetMouseVars(); return; }

                  // add link
                  var link = {source: mousedown_node, target: mouseup_node};
                  this.graph.links.push(link);

                  // select new link
                  this.selected_link = link;
                  this.selected_node = null;

                  // enable zoom
                  g.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom"), this.rescale);
                  redraw();
                } 
              }
      )
      ;

    nodeExit = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(this.graph.nodes)
      .exit().transition()
      .attr("r", 0)
      .remove();

    if (d3.event) {
      // prevent browser's default behavior
      d3.event.preventDefault();
    }

    this.force
    .nodes(this.graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", this.tick);



  },

  spliceLinksForNode: function(node) {
    toSplice = this.graph.links.filter(
      function(l) { 
        return (l.source === node) || (l.target === node); 
      }
    );
    toSplice.map(
      function(l) {
        this.graph.links.splice(this.graph.links.indexOf(l), 1); 
      }
    );
  },

  keydown: function() {
    if (!this.selected_node && !this.selected_link) return;
    switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
      case 8: // backspace
      case 46: { // delete
        if (this.selected_node) {
          this.graph.nodes.splice(this.graph.nodes.indexOf(this.selected_node), 1);
          spliceLinksForNode(this.selected_node);
        }
        else if (this.selected_link) {
          this.graph.links.splice(this.graph.links.indexOf(this.selected_link), 1);
        }
        this.selected_link = null;
        this.selected_node = null;
        redraw();
        break;
      }
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at your code, my hunch is you're mixing contexts for `this`. In all your d3 mouseover callback functions, you're attempting to call polymer properties and methods, but your context has changed, so `this.selected_node = null` et al does not actually refer to your Polymer property. To solve this, you can bind your Polymer `this` to the callback function:

```
.on("mousedown", function(d) { 
        //your callback code
    }.bind(this) );
```

Now call `this` from within your callback will refer to the Polymer `this`.